# Japanese Imperial Calendar JSF

Tags: jsf, calendar

Is there a JSF control available that displays date in Japanese Imperial Calendar Format?

Comment: Are you looking for a component that can display/select dates in the Japanese format, or what do you mean by "control"?

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl Sorry for a delayed response to your query! The years in the Japanese Imperial calendar is reset to zero with a new Era whenever a new Emperor is coronated. For example, 2013 is 25 years since the current emperor occupied the throne and hence the 6-Jan-2013 is actually 6-Jan-25 for Japan. So, I would like to know if there is a control that not only displays the labels for the days of the week in Japanese but also enable this Imperial Calendar notation.